# Parse Mailgun headers

Tags: php, json, mailgun

I have the following JSON from a Mailgun webhook (Delivered) that I need to extract the subject line from.

They do not appear to be following a typical key value JSON format, short of a bunch of foreach loops is there a way to extract this data?

```
[["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8734663311733; Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": "eb663d73ae0a4d6c9153cc0aec8b7520"}]], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", "Test deliver webhook"], ["From", "Bob <bob@fvrs.org>"], ["To", "Alice <alice@example.com>"], ["Message-Id", "<20130503182626.18666.16540@fvrs.org>"], ["X-Mailgun-Variables", "{\"my_var_1\": \"Mailgun Variable #1\", \"my-var-2\": \"awesome\"}"], ["Date", "Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Sender", "bob@fvrs.org"]]
```

Comment: Even if there was an alternative way, the `foreach` would probably be the fastest/most efficient. I would make an angry phone call to Mailgun for outputting such a ridiculous JSON format though. "Email service for developers" my ass.

Comment: Why not use Mandrill? My own research leads me to think they're competitively priced and much better in their support.

Comment: I switched to Mailgun today after months of complaints that emails were not being received even though they were marked Delivered by Mandrill. Client was upset Mandrill could offer no explanation.

Comment: Fascinating and good to know, thanks!

Comment: Also, Mailgun support replied to me in under three hours today, a Sunday. Client is reporting better deliverability so far.

Comment: @sjagr search "Mandrill delivered but not received," apparently I'm not alone. Disappointing, I really like their dashboard and features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not a dictionary is because in emails you can have the same header appear more than once.

You just a single loop, though:

```
$subject = null;
foreach ($data as $header) {
    if ($header[0] == 'Subject') {
        $subject = $header[1];
        break;
    }
}
```